# Django error: AttributeError at 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'

Tags: python, django

**models.py:**

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
    from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
    from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        # code
        def create_user(self, uid, pass):
            # code

    class user(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        # code    
        objects = UserManager()    
        # code    

    class appUser(user):
    # code
```

**views.py**

```
from projectname.app.models import appUser

def index_view(request):
        # code    
        appUser.objects.create_user(uid_variable, pass_variable)
        # code
```

**settings.py**

```
#code
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #code
    'projectname.app',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.appUser'
#code
```

When I am trying to call a create-user method in view this exception appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `appUser` is a subclass of `user`. If `user` is not an abstract base class, then `appUser` will not inherit the manager, and you will need to redeclare it.

```
class appUser(user):
    objects = UserManager()
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance):

> Managers defined on non-abstract base classes are not inherited by child classes. If you want to reuse a manager from a non-abstract base, redeclare it explicitly on the child class. These sorts of managers are likely to be fairly specific to the class they are defined on, so inheriting them can often lead to unexpected results (particularly as far as the default manager goes). Therefore, they aren’t passed onto child classes.

Having your `appUser` model subclass `user` is complex, you might encounter other difficulties. I would avoid it if possible, or at least make `user` abstract.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. You are right, I didn't take into account peculiarities of Managers inheritance. Your answer has helped me.